# Partitioning - when to create new scheme?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the following partition setup on a table.

[image]

I'm wanting to create a new partition that begins on 2019-01-01.

Is the the correct way of doing it, and can it be run now so it's ready to go for 2019?

```
ALTER DATABASE mydatabase ADD FILEGROUP [Year7FileGroup]  
GO
ALTER DATABASE mydatabase
  ADD FILE  
  (NAME = N'data_year7',
  FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQL2014\MSSQL\DATA\data_year73.ndf',
  SIZE = 5000MB,
  FILEGROWTH = 500MB)
  TO FILEGROUP [Year7FileGroup]
GO
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME psYearlyPartition_Log
    NEXT USED Year7FileGroup;
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION pfYearlyPartition_Log()
    SPLIT RANGE('20190101');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I would encourage you to read Dan Guzman's excellent post on [Table Partitioning Best Practices](http://www.dbdelta.com/table-partitioning-best-practices/).  It does a great job of explaining why:

> "One needs a good understanding of how the RANGE LEFT/RIGHT
>   specification affects partition setup and management."

Now, on to your question.

I'm a little puzzled why you're adding a new partition for '2019-01-01', when your latest partition seems to be for '2016-01-01'.  Since you're trying to add a new partition for '2019-01-01', I would've expected to already see partitions for '2017-01-01' and '2018-01-01'.

In any event, when you're planning on using the `SPLIT` command, the main thing you want to consider is minimizing data movement between existing partitions.  Pre-defining empty partitions 'before' the minimum value you can have and 'after' the maximum value you can have will allow you to minimize data movement when using the `SPLIT`.  Referencing Dan's post:

**The actions performed by a SPLIT of a RANGE LEFT partition function:**

- For each table/index using the affected partition scheme(s), move
  rows from the existing split partition that are less than or equal to
  the new boundary into the newly created partition on the left

**The actions performed by a SPLIT of a RANGE RIGHT partition function:**

- For each table/index using the affected partition scheme(s), move
  rows from the existing split partition that are greater than or equal
  to the new boundary into the newly create partition on the right

It *looks* like you might be using `RANGE RIGHT` partition.  As long as you currently do not have any dates that are greater than or equal to '2019-01-01', there should be no data movement and the `SPLIT` should execute very quickly.  You definitely want to get the '2019-01-01' partition defined before you get too much data in your table with dates greater than or equal to that date.

The main point I'm trying to stress is to make sure you already have partition boundaries defined well ahead of the data that currently exists on the table.  Many times, you can go ahead and define partitions ranges years in advance of the data, but you should always monitor your partitioned tables to ensure you aren't creeping up on an ending boundary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Scott, very helpful.  Yes I would have expected that also, but partitions were forgotten to be created for 2016,2017,2018. So starting with a new partition for 2019 onwards.

Answer (score -1):

Before table partitioning, please think about some point :
1. Is partition column used in where clause.
2. Size of table 
3. Partition key good to have integer value or timestamp.
4. If going for date range partition, never user max. Always create some partition in advance for the future range.